# CDK Overlay style import

Tags: angular, angular-cdk

Hi I'm creating my own modal dialog using CDK and within a library. I've managed to wire everything up, but the dialog presents itself at that the bottom inline with the document.

I believe the problem is with the styles not being imported correctly.

I have the statement in /src/lib/components/modal/modal.component.css :

```
@import "~@angular/cdk/overlay-prebuilt.css";
```

when I build the app, and use it in the demo app I cannot see the styles being applied on the element. The examples that I have seen is for the styles to be imported into the styles.scss and it generally assumes that it is for an application rather than a library. Is there something different I need to do for a library ?

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue here is that you're not importing in the global stylesheet. Move the import to the global stylesheet e.g. the one that the angular.json file points to with the property "styles."